# Delete group when its observation does not contain certain values in SAS

Tags: group-by, sas, proc-sql

Refer to below table, an ID is considered as complete if at least one of its group having Day 1 to Day 3 (Duplicate allowed).
I need to remove ID which has Group not having full Day 1 to Day 3.

```
ID   Group     Day
1     A        1
1     A        1
1     A        2
1     A        3
1     B        1
1     B        3
2     A        1
2     A        3
2     B        2
```

Expected result

```
ID   Group     Day
1     A        1
1     A        1
1     A        2
1     A        3
1     B        1
1     B        3
```

With this reference, [Delete the group that none of its observation contain the certain value in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863590/delete-the-group-that-none-of-its-observation-contain-the-certain-value-in-sas)
I have tried below code but it cannot remove ID 2.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TEMP AS SELECT
* FROM HAVE
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(DAY)=1 AND MAX(DAY)=3
;QUIT;

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TEMP1 AS SELECT
* FROM TEMP WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM TEMP
WHERE DAY=2)
;QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to find the set of ID values where the ID has at least one GROUP that has all three DAY values?  Find the list of IDs as a subquery and use it to subset the original data.

The key thing in subquery is you want there to be 3 distinct values of DAY.  If your data could have other values of DAY (like missing or 4) then use a WHERE clause to only keep the values you want to count.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
  select * from have
  where id in 
   (select id from have 
    where day in (1,2,3)
    group by id,group
    having count(distinct day)=3
   )
;
quit;
```

Comment: Simple and succinct. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the dataset with a removal list. For example:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
        select *
        from have
        where cats(group, id) NOT IN(select cats(group, id) from removal_list)
    ;
quit;
```

**Creating the Removal List**

This method will prevent you from having to do a Cartesian product on all IDs, groups, and days to create your removal list.

Assume that your data is sorted by `ID`, `group`, and `day`.

1. For each ID, the first day in the group must be 1
2. For each ID, all days in the group after the first day must have a difference of 1 from the previous day

Code:

```
data removal_list;
    set have;
    by ID Group Day;
    retain flag_remove_group;

    lag_day = lag(day);

    /* Reset flag_remove_group at the start of each (ID, Group).
       Check if the first day is > 1. If it is, set the removal flag.
    */
    if(first.group) then do;
        call missing(lag_day);

        if(day > 1) then flag_remove_group = 1;
            else flag_remove_group = 0;
    end;

    /* If it's not the first (ID, Group), check if days 
       are skipped between observations 
    */
    if(NOT first.group AND (day - lag_day) NE 1) then flag_remove_group = 1;

    if(flag_remove_group) then output;

    keep id group;
run;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I missed out the potential cases of duplicates and diff(day) ^= 1, in these cases, (day-lag_day) may be invalid.

Comment: Can you dedupe your dataset first, or do you always want to remove those cases as well?

Comment: it cannot be dedupe, the duplicate has to be remained if it belongs to the ID having 1,2,3 day by group.